# Trouble getting the explicit solution

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$\newcommand{\diff}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$
I was given the following ODE, and I have to rewrite the implicit solution as the explicit solution. However, I don't know if my answer is even correct.
$$\begin{align}x^2\diff&=y-xy \\ x^2\diff&=y(1-x) \\ \frac{dy}y&=\frac{1-x}{x^2} \\ \int_{-1}^y\frac{dt}{t}&=\int_{-1}^x \frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{1}{s}ds \\ \ln\lvert y\rvert-\ln\lvert-1\rvert&= [-\frac{1}t-\ln\lvert t\rvert]\Bigg\vert_{-1}^x \\ \ln\lvert y\rvert &= -\frac{1}x-\ln\lvert x\rvert-(1-\ln\lvert-1 \rvert) \\ \ln \lvert y\rvert&= -\frac{1}{x}-\ln\lvert x\rvert -1\end{align} $$

The bottom line is the implicit solution, and I am wondering how do I arrive at the explicit solution which is supposed to be the following:

> $$y=\frac{e^{-(1+\frac{1}x)}}{x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use both sides as the power of $e$, plus the properties of exponents and logarithms, as shown below

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\ln \lvert y\rvert & = -\frac{1}{x}-\ln\lvert x\rvert -1 \\
\ln \lvert y\rvert & = -\left(\frac{1}{x} + 1\right) - \ln\lvert x\rvert \\
e^{\ln \lvert y\rvert} & = e^{-\left(\frac{1}{x} + 1\right) - \ln\lvert x\rvert} \\
y & = e^{-\left(\frac{1}{x} + 1\right)}e^{- \ln\lvert x\rvert} \\
y & = e^{-\left(\frac{1}{x} + 1\right)}\left(\frac{1}{e^{\ln\lvert x\rvert}}\right) \\
y & = \frac{e^{-\left(1+\frac{1}x\right)}}{x}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$